# Build durable architecture with Websphere MQ clients

Tags: ibm-mq

How can you create a durable architecture environment using MQ Client and server if the clients don't allow you to persist messages nor do they allow for assured delivery?

Just trying to figure out how you can build a salable / durable architecture if the clients don't appear to contain any of the necessary components required to persist data.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware messaging was born of the need to persist data locally to mitigate the effects of failures of the remote node or of the network.  The idea at the time was that the queue manager was installed locally on the box where the application lives and was treated as part of the transport stack.  For instance you might install TCP and WMQ as a transport and some apps would use TCP while others used WMQ.

In the intervening 20 years, the original problems that led to the creation of MQSeries (Now WebSphere MQ) have largely been solved.  The networks have improved by several nines of availability and high availability hardware and software clustering have provided options to keep the different components available 24x7.

So the practices in widespread use today to address your question follow two basic approaches.  Either make the components highly available so that the client can always find a messaging server, or put a QMgr where the application lives in order to provide local queueing.

Answer (score 1):

The default operation of MQ is that when a message is sent (MQPUT or in JMS terms producer.send), the application does not get a response back on the MQPUT call until the message has reached a queue on a queue manager.  i.e. MQPUT is a synchronous call, and if you get a completion code of OK, that means that the queue manager to which the client application is connected has received the message successfully.  It may not yet have reached its ultimate destination, but it has reached the protection of an MQ Server, and therefore you can rely on MQ to look after the message and forward it on to where it needs to get to.

Whether client connected, or locally bound to the queue manager, applications sending messages are responsible for their data until an MQPUT call returns successfully.  Similarly, receiving applications are responsible for their data once they get it from a successful MQGET (or JMS consumer.receive) call.

There are multiple levels of message protection are available.
If you are using non-persistent messages and asynchronous PUTs, then you are effectively saying it doesn't matter too much whether the messages reach their destination (although they generally will).
If you want MQ to really look after your messages, use synchronous PUTs as described above, persistent messages, and perform your PUTs and GETs within transactions (aka syncpoint) so you have full application control over the commit points.

If you have very unreliable networks such that you expect to regularly fail to get the messages to a server, and expect to need regular retries such that you need client-side message protection, one option you could investigate is MQ Telemetry (e.g. in WebSphere MQ V7.1) which is designed for low bandwidth and/or unreliable network communications, as a route into the wider MQ.